# Using PEAR XMLRPC2 inside wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, pear, xml-rpc

I am trying to run the PEAR XMLRPC inside a plugin function to do some validation.  It is all working fine in a standalone app that in a folder on my server, but as soon as I put all the files into my plugin folder, the:

```
require_once 'XML/RPC2/Client.php';
```

doesn't work.  The Client.php file return an error:

```
Warning:  require_once(XML/RPC2/Exception.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream:
```

So i assume it has to do with relative vs non-relative files, but I can't seem to figure out why it works outside of wordpress just fine.

If I start changing all the

```
require_once 'XML/RPC2...
```

to be the absolute path on the server the errors start going away, but I feel like I shouldn't have to change the source of PEAR and XMLRPC to do what i need.  Any Suggestions?

Comment: `XML/RPC2/Client.php` is trying to load `XML/RPC2/XML/RPC2/Exception.php` maybe?

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, but it works fine outside of wordpress. It just feels like i should have to change the include paths of the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the PHP include path:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $pathToPearLibs);
require_once($pathToPearLibs . 'XML/RPC2/Client.php');
```

This will give PHP one more (correct) place to look after it attempts to load from the wrong place.

Comment: Where $pathToPearLibs is the absolute path to the PEAR source?

Comment: Yes, a path on the filesystem where `require_once('XML/RPC2/Exception.php')` will work. You can derive it from the plugin directory in Wordpress: `plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/pearstuff/'`.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error.  Its finding CLient.php fine, but not the require within the PEAR and XMLRPC systems. So it can find and run "wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/PEAR/XML/RPC2/Client.php", but this file calls "XML/RPC2/Exception.php" and fails.

Comment: I just gave this a whirl and it seems to work here. You might want to doublecheck the path you are setting. https://gist.github.com/3854456

Comment: It seems maybe is a wordpress issue then because I just duplicated your steps and it is still failing. https://gist.github.com/3854532.  Although it seems it can't find PEAR.php now. Ok seems that I just had to put the PEAR files back into the PEAR folder, rather than the rm -rf.